# Return char* as pointer instead of string in struct

Tags: c#, c, swig

I have a C struct and a method defined as below:

```
struct foobar {
    HGLOBAL  hmem;
    char    *pmem;
};

void quux(unsigned char *pmem);
```

When generating wrappers for this struct, SWIG automatically sets the return type of `pmem` to be `string`:

```
public class foobar : global::System.IDisposable 
{
    ...

    public string pmem {
      set {
        MYLIB_SWIGPINVOKE.foobar_pmem_set(swigCPtr, value);
      } 
      get {
        string ret = MYLIB_SWIGPINVOKE.foobar_pmem_get(swigCPtr);
        return ret;
      } 
    }
}
```

But sets the method's parameter to be of type `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char`:

```
public static void quux(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char pmem) 
{
    MYLIB_SWIGPINVOKE.quux(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char.getCPtr(pmem));
}
```

I need these parameters to be of the same type, and since `pmem` should be binary I'd like them both to be `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char`.  The docs mention that this is possible but don't give an example of how to change this behavior.  All data storage is managed on the C side, the C# side is just giving the right pointer to the method.

How can I change the wrapped type of `pmem` to be `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char`?

Comment: The C declaration for `foobar.pmem` is clearly a `char *`, while the parameter to the function is `unsigned char *`.  Can you change the `foobar.pmem` to an `unsigned char *' so that they match?

Comment: That would fix it, but I can't touch the header file unfortunately.  It belongs to another group and they don't see it as a valid change (if it ain't broke...)

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case it __is__ broke :-(.  Perhaps you could give SWIG a different header file declaring the same structure and function?  I'm not that familiar with SWIG, but unless there is some way to tell it the proper type you may be out of luck.  Although technically `char*` can point to bytes, so can `void*` and even `int*`, but that doesn't make it proper code.  `unsigned char*` is the proper type to use for bytes, and unless the function is used for other data structures too (probably a bad design), using the same pointer types *is* important, for this very reason.

Comment: Yep, I completely agree.  I'm just hoping for some SWIG magic that could perform the cast for me (and also stop converting the type to a `string`).